# show random values from array of array

Tags: php, kohana

Below is a array generated by a query builder.

```
   $random_array =  Array ( [0] => Array ( [text] => A great time was had by all! ) 
            [1] => Array ( [text] => KILL SHOT ) 
            [2] => Array ( [text] => How is it possible) 
            [3] => Array ( [text] => http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KwGOZpbxU9g ) 
            [4] => Array ( [text] => http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KwGOZpbxU9g ) 
          )
```

Currently i am doing like this to print the random value

```
print_r(array_rand($random_array,1));
```

This is printing the array key as 3 or 1 etc(random from above array).I want to print the value of the key and not the key.

e.g I want to print the random value like this `"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KwGOZpbxU9g" or "A great time was had by all!"` instead of `3 or 1` which is printing now.

Is it possible to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have one more line of code as shown below:

```
$array_key = array_rand($random_array,1); //get the key
print_r( $random_array[$array_key] );     //use the key to print value
```

Comment: This is printing the value as "Array ( [text] => A great time was had by all! )".Is any way to just show "A great time was had by all!" alone without array notation.

Comment: It would then be `print_r( $random_array[$array_key]['text'] );`.

Comment: print_r( $random_array[$array_key]['text'] ); Working as required.

Answer (score 0):

What about simply calling

```
$randNumber = rand(0,count($random_array))-1; //index in array starts with 0    
print (string) $random_array[$randNumber];
```